# Does a door on the stairs count as basement egress?

Tags: basement, egress

I am looking at finishing a basement room in my 120 year old house. There is a landing 64" up from the basement floor where it turns and there are an additional five steps up to the level of the main living area. At this landing there is a full door that exits directly outside. The room I want to finish is at the bottom of the stairs.

Is an egress window needed?

The small town I live in doesn't have a building inspector in the winter. City hall has been no help.

Comment: Will there be any bedrooms in the basement?

Comment: I would guess that an egress window's intent is to provide a second way of exit in case of emergency if the primary exit were blocked, so no matter the location of the primary exit, I'd think there would need to be a secondary way out.  But if your small town doesn't have a building inspector during the winter, that seems unusual, as then any construction permits wouldn't be able to be closed out.  Perhaps see if there's a trusted home builder or general contractor that might give some insight into local requirements.

Comment: Related discussion: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/36405/do-i-need-an-egress-window-in-a-basement-room-not-used-as-a-bedroom

Comment: Where in the world do you live?

Comment: Will there be a door at the bottom of the stairs?

Comment: There is a door about three feet beyond the end of the stairs that opens into the room. I live in a small town, (pop. 1800) in central Wisconsin. I have a friend on the city counsel who just confirmed that the inspector that covers our area goes south for the winter. When he comes back in spring , he looks over the projects that were completed over winter, as much as he can, and signs off if doesn't see anything obviously out of code.

Comment: There will be no bedroom. There will be a TV, poker table and a small couch.

Comment: Personally I would not consider 2 exits off of one staircase (to outside and upstairs) to be 2 separate fire exits. This is separate from any code issues, just personal risk management.

Comment: So, there is a finished habitable room that is not a sleeping room, and that has two closed doors *not three* between it and the outside, and no other way of exiting.  Is that right?  I think if that's right and without knowing your local code, I would continue, with reasonable hope the inspector will be happy with it.  Or ask a local contractor who has enough experience to have been both approved and failed by this inspector.

Answer (score 1):

Under the International Residential Code there's egress and there's emergency escape. Your front door probably qualifies as the egress. An emergency escape in addition to an egress (or an additional egress) is required for any basement larger than 200 ft<sup>2</sup>. An emergency escape is also required for any sleeping room. See sections [R310](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch03_SecR310) and [R311](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch03_SecR311) from the code.

Your 18"x36" window is unfortunate, as it's deficient in square footage and height. See [R310.2.1](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch03_SecR310.2.1) and [R310.2.2](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch03_SecR310.2.2). Note that the bottom of the emergency escape must be within 44" of the floor, [IRC R310.2.3](https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P1/chapter-3-building-planning#IRC2021P1_Pt03_Ch03_SecR310.2.3). There are window well requirements too, assuming that conformance would require digging.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I think I'll just proceed as planned. Worst case scenario is, I'll have to remove one of the 18"x 36" basement windows with something removable. Hope I don't have to enlarge the opening in the two foot thick stone foundation.

Comment: @golfer82, I just read the first sentence from my first link and discovered that I screwed this answer up. I'm revising it. Sorry for not investing minimal effort in actually reading anything with your context in mind.